# Command doesn't work on top level MenuItem in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, command, menuitem

It works fine if the MenuItem doesn't have a sub MenuItem, like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}"/>
```

but, when I add a sub MenuItem to it, the Command doesn't work:

```
<MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}">
    <MenuItem />
</MenuItem>
```

click event also doesn't work like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Open" Click="MenuItem_Click">
    <MenuItem />
</MenuItem>
```

when I try to add the Command to the header:

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                 <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}"/>
            </TextBlock.InputBindings>
            Open
        </TextBlock>
    </MenuItem.Header>
    <MenuItem />
</MenuItem>
```

the Command works but the sub MenuItem doesn't show.

Any help will be appreciate, and forgive my half-baked English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sub `MenuItems` the click event is used (and expected by the user) to show the sub-menu. To react upon a submenu opening use the event `SubmenuOpened`.

If you *really* want to be able to open a sub menu and click on the "Open", you could use this snipper, but I'd really not advice it:

```
<MenuItem SubmenuOpened="MenuItem_OnSubmenuOpened"> <!-- handle sub menu opening if desired -->
  <MenuItem.Header>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Open V2</Button> <!-- handle click on "Open" if desired; doesn't open sub menu! -->
  </MenuItem.Header>
  <MenuItem />
</MenuItem>
```

Note that I have tested this with "Open" not being the top level menu item.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I want to refresh something  before the submenu opened,but It seems like there is no `SubmenuOpening` event. I finally fix this problem in this: `<MenuItem Header = "Open" MouseEnter="MenuItem_MouseEnter">`.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Chao: You could also generate the menu dynamically by using a binding on the `MenuItem.Items` property. In the getter which will be invoked every time the menu opens (or you can raise a property changed event), so you can modify the contents.